# How to use BeautifulSoup to get attribute value if the attribute name duplicated

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, attributes, find

I wrote below Python codes to parse HTML through BeautifulSoup:

```
parsed_html = BeautifulSoup('<img id = \'defualtPagePic\' src="http://my.com/images/realTarget.jpg" alt="test" src="http://my.com/images/fakeTarget.jpg" alt="too bad" onError="this.src=\'http://my.com/images/veryBad.jpg\';" />', "html.parser")
print("a >> "+ str(parsed_html.find(id="defualtPagePic").attrs))
print("b >> "+ str(parsed_html.find(id="defualtPagePic")['src']))
```

And this is the execution result:

```
a >> {'id': 'defualtPagePic', 'src': 'http://my.com/images/fakeTarget.jpg', 'alt': 'too bad', 'onerror': "this.src='http://my.com/images/veryBad.jpg';"}
b >> http://my.com/images/fakeTarget.jpg
```

I want to get the "realTarget.jpg" but I am failed and get the "fakeTarget.jpg".
I think the reason is BeautifulSoup always get the latest value for a specific attribute name.

Any advice on this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could switch to using the `lxml` parser as follows:

```
html = '<img id = \'defualtPagePic\' src="http://my.com/images/realTarget.jpg" alt="test" src="http://my.com/images/fakeTarget.jpg" alt="too bad" onError="this.src=\'http://my.com/images/veryBad.jpg\';" />'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
print(soup.img['src'])
```

This would then display:

```
http://my.com/images/realTarget.jpg
```

If you don't have it, [`lxml`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) will need to be installed separately.